# save that photo into store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

When I take photo from camera I have to save that photo into store.
I am getting `data:image/jpeg;base64` string for that Image but I am not able to save it into Store.
Please provide me some guide line.
Thanks

Comment: sure u re not exceeding the 5mb localStorage limit ¿?